# Laravel php artisan serve page not found

Tags: php, laravel, visual-studio-code

Hello guys i'm trying to build\start a PHP existing web app made with Laravel. I made this:

1.Installed XAMPP for PHP version 7.4, also configure Apache Server and tested with `localhost` and that is working

2.Installed `composer` and connected with PHP version 7.4

3.Intalled Node.js

4.`npm install` in the project

5.`composer install` in the project add the missing packages

In VS Code terminal I add command `php artisan serve` on adress `http://127.0.0.1:8000/` to run the application. But I get :

> This page isn’t working127.0.0.1 sent an invalid response.
> ERR_INVALID_REDIRECT

Any suggestion?

Comment: how are node.js and visual studio code related to a laravel application?

Comment: Im new, edit my question and correct me what i'm trying. This i the project structure i got:

Comment: @LelioFaieta https://prnt.sc/107m4w0 <- on the link

Comment: If you press F12 (in most browsers) you get the developer tools and in those there generally is a "Network" tab. Open that and then press refresh on the page and see the exact response you are getting for the request. It should be a 301 response and the response header should have a "Location" entry for the browser to understand it as a redirect. Also sidenote, if you're using `php artisan serve` then XAMPP is not involved at all in this process

Comment: @apokryfos i get this-> https://prnt.sc/107mm8s

Comment: if you click on the erroring entry there should be something showing up on the right with more details on the specific request like request headers, response headers cookies etc

Comment: What URL are you on? `http://localhost` or `http://localhost:8000`? No need to `php artisan serve` if you want to use XAMP - or vice versa

Comment: ```.env``` was not configurated. Thank you very much for your help